# How can I "click" all div in the firefox console?

Tags: javascript, firefox, console

How can I perform a "click" action on all the rows that start with "label style-scope ytcp-button" in the following html:

```
<div class="label style-scope ytcp-button">Edit Draft</div>
```

Here what i tried

```
$("div[class^=label style-scope ytcp-button]")​​​​​​​​​​​​​​.click();
```

it seem not work.

Comment: You can't use JQuery in the console. You need to use pure JavaScript. Like `document.getElementsByClassName("label style-scope ytcp-button");`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the simple JS method `querySelectorAll()`.

```js
const els = document.querySelectorAll('.label.style-scope.ytcp-button');

els.forEach((el) => {
  el.click();
  console.log('clicked');
});
```

Comment: can you tell me , 
if i want to click on text where default text in div = 
EDIT DRAFT ?

`<div class="label style-scope ytcp-button">Edit Draft</div>`

Comment: @Mena you should be able to get that working by adding an if condition. Something like this:

`if (el.innerHTML === 'Edit Draft') { el.click(); console.log('clicked'); }`

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the Apostrophe. You should write like this:-

```
         $("div[class^='label style-scope ytcp-button']").click();
```

Run the code snippet below, it will not run alert method on clicking on the last div as the "**ytcp-button**" class is missing in the last div.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div[class^='label style-scope ytcp-button']").click(function(){
        alert("You have Click a Specific Class");
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="label style-scope ytcp-button">It will Show Alert</div>
    <div class="label style-scope ytcp-button">It will Show Alert</div>
    <div class="label style-scope ytcp-button">It will Show Alert</div>
    <div class="label style-scope">It will not Show Alert</div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: that is not run on firefox console.